# how to find the index of a reoccurring word in a string without spaces

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to write the code to output the index of each location that a word occurs in a string that has no spaces.

Specifically the gene: 'act' within the sequence: 'avdgagtactsdfactactfgactlkact'.

The output should be:

Locations of gene: [7, 13, 16, 21, 26]'

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression match object has the handy [`.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) method:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "avdgagtactsdfactactfgactlkact"

In [3]: [m.start() for m in re.finditer("act", s)]
Out[3]: [7, 13, 16, 21, 26]
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative could be to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
sequence = 'avdgagtactsdfactactfgactlkact'
gene = 'act'

result = [i for i in range(len(sequence) - len(gene) + 1) if sequence[i:].startswith(gene)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[7, 13, 16, 21, 26]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this:

```
j = 'avdgagtactsdfactactfgactlkact'
[i for i, x in enumerate(j) if j[i:i+3] == 'act']

[7, 13, 16, 21, 26]
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer with regular expressions:

```
import re

gene = 'act'
sequence = 'avdgagtactsdfactactfgactlkact'

[m.start() for m in re.finditer(gene, sequence)]
```